# detect barcode reader input

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode

here is my code to focus on "text2display" if clicked anywhere on the form (which is in a popup). but, how if they "tab" and navigate elsewhere (e.g. browser url), how to detect that and return focus back to ""text2display"?

```
$("#barcode_form").click(function(){
  var focusedElement = "";
  $(":focus").each(function(){  
    focusedElement = $(this).attr("id")                
  });
  if(focusedElement == ""){
    $('#text2display').focus()
  }
})
```

Comment: What browser is this going to be running in? Is it on a mobile device or a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting the .blur(); function. Whenever an element has "focus" and the user leaves the "focused" item, "blur" is invoked and sends an event back to the element. An example to follow.

```
if(focusedElement == ""){
  //if our focused element is empty
  $('#text2display').live('blur', function(){
    //when the target loses focus, we invoke blur, the next line focuses again.
    //it's also a best practice to do something like fading in the border, 
    $("#text2display").focus();
  });
}
```

Also, if I may suggest, it would be a good idea to let the user know that their focus has returned to that element. The best way to do this is to do something like adding a 'red' border, then fading that border out. One way is as follows ->

```
if(focusedElement == ""){
  //if our focused element is empty
  $('#text2display').live('blur', function(){
    //when the target loses focus, we invoke blur, the next line focuses again.
    //it's also a best practice to do something like fading in the border, 
    $("#text2display").focus(function(){
      $(this).animate({
        //when the element has been re-focused, we'll give it a red border briefly.
        borderColor: '#ff0000';
      }, function(){
           //once the animation completes, fade the border out                    
           $(this).animate({ borderColor: 'transparent' }, 2000);
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Also, because we don't want resizing issues, we need to add some CSS to our inputs

```
input{
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

This should work well for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply Ohgodwhy, but seems not to be working. besides, i am looking for a replacement for "$("#barcode_form").click(function()" since i want to detect any input from barcode when the popup is on

Comment: $("#barcode_form").click(function()
        {  
             var focusedElement = "";
             
             $(":focus").each(function() 
             {  
                    focusedElement = $(this).attr("id")                
              });
              
              
              
              if(focusedElement == "")
              {
                  
                  $('#text2display').live('blur', function()
                  {
                        $("#text2display").focus()
                  });
                }
              
              
        })

Comment: It's actually late, and I might have completed misinterpreted your needs in the original question.