# VB.NET Event when Bar Code Scanned

Tags: vb.net, barcode-scanner

I have a USB bar code scanner that is acting as an HID keyboard emulation device. I want a web page that, for testing purposes, pops up a JavaScript alert when a scan is done. I don't want to tie the event to any visible control such as a textbox so thus, I won't have focus on any control to capture the scan input. Can this be done? I'm using VS 2010 with .NET 4.0 and VB.NET with a Symbol USB bar code scanner. Thanks ... Bob

Comment: It would be simple with a textbox and doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530347/detect-barcode-reader-input Otherwise without a input control you'd have to hook up a  `document.onkeydown = function() {` concenate the `barcodeInput += ChrCodeToLetter(window.event.keyCode)` then on a timer event `(if barcodeInput.Length > 5) {alert(barcodeInput);`

Answer (score 0):

Different bar code scanners can output different control characters like tab and line feeds. You should read the manual for your scanner.

You should be able to pick those up with a key press event handler.

Comment: To my knowledge, the key press event requires focus on a control. I want to capture this scan without any controls on my web page. Checked my manual (http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=15346603apdf&sliceId=&dialogID=51113397&stateId=0%200%2051105181

Comment: You have to have focus on the view port of the page. You could use this that uses jquery. https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys#readme